# I am trying to understand a logical error

Tags: python, pandas

hotels.csv:

```
id,name,city,capacity,available
134,Tourist Sunn,Anchorage,4,no
188,Snow Palace, New Delhi,5,yes
655,City Break,Porto Novo,3,yes
```

cards.csv:

```
number,expiration,cvc,holder
"1234","12/26","123","JOHN SMITH"
"5678","12/28","456","JANE SMITH"
```

Hello

I am writing a small program. It uses both csv files above. The user is request to submit his hotel id.

a) if the hotel is free then he will verify its credit card and a PDF receipt will be generated.

b)if the hotel is not available a message will be displayed.

c) if credit card information are wrong he will get a message.

I wrote the code below. I was successful to achieve step b and c...I m stuck with step a. No matter i enter genuine data from cards.csv i still get the message " there is a problem with your payment"
I do not know how to solve it...any hint that may help, or anything to read in order to understand what is wrong.

Thanks for any help

---

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("hotels.csv", dtype={"id": str})

df_cards = pd.read_csv("cards.csv", dtype=str).to_dict()


class Hotel:
    def __init__(self, hotel_id):
        self.hotel_id = hotel_id
        self.name = df.loc[df["id"] == self.hotel_id, "name"].squeeze()


    def book(self):
        """book a hotel  by changing its availability to no"""
        df.loc[df["id"] == self.hotel_id, "available"] = "no"
        df.to_csv("hotels.csv", index=False)


    def available(self):
        """check if the hotel is available"""
        availability = df.loc[df["id"] == self.hotel_id, "available"].squeeze()
        if availability == "yes":
            return True
        else:
            return False


class ReservationTicket:
    def __init__(self, customer_name, hotel_object):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.hotel = hotel_object


    def generate(self):
        content = f"""
         Thank you for  your reservation !
         Here are your booking data
         Name: {self.customer_name}
         Hotel name : {self.hotel.name}
         """
        return content


class CreditCard:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number


    def validate(self, expiration, holder, cvc):
        card_data = {"number": self.number, "expiration": expiration,
                     "holder": holder, "cvc": cvc}
        m_data = frozenset(card_data.items())
        if m_data in df_cards:
            return True
        else:
            return False


print(df)
hotel_ID = input("Enter the Id of the hotel :")
hotel = Hotel(hotel_ID)

if hotel.available():
    credit_card = CreditCard(number="1234")
    if credit_card.validate(expiration="12/26", holder="JOHN SMITH", cvc="123"):
        hotel.book()
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        reservation_ticket = ReservationTicket(customer_name=name, hotel_object=hotel)
        print(reservation_ticket.generate())
    else:
        print("there was a problem with your payment")

else:
    print("Hotel is not free")
```

I tried the 3 steps of the program and i was able to achieve only 2.. I failed to achieve the most significant one : the first one.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code and check what happens inside CreditCard.validate?

Comment: Is the problem `m_data in df_cards`, because `m_data` is a frozenset of tuples, not a column name from `df_cards`? I recommend adding some print statements to print `m_data` and `df_cards`

Comment: replace `df_cards = pd.read_csv("cards.csv", dtype=str).to_dict()` with `df_cards = [frozenset(card.items()) for card in pd.read_csv("cards.csv", dtype=str).to_dict(orient="records")]` and everything works

Comment: otherwise, you could turn both m_data and df_cards into sets of tuples, but I assume there are good reasons why you are using frozensets

Answer (score 1):

### Short version

Replace `df_cards = pd.read_csv("cards.csv", dtype=str).to_dict()` with `df_cards = [frozenset(card.items()) for card in pd.read_csv("cards.csv", dtype=str).to_dict(orient="records")]`

### Long version

`df_cards` is a dict, `frozenset(card.items())` is a set. Comparing the two, they're never going to be equal to one another, as they're different types.

If you want to get it working, you have to either:

1. turn the df_cards into a frozenset too,
2. turn `card.items()` into a dict, or
3. turn them both into another common format, such as a tuple.